# How to make use of Enums for making response uniform while integrating different parts

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, enums

I am working on `validate` API, in which, I call the `validate` method of a Library class, which returns `List<ModelProblem>` along with several other validations which I defined at my service.

The class structure of `ModelProblem` defined in the library, is as follows:

```
public class ModelProblem {
  private final ModelProblemCode modelProblemCode;
  private final String message;
  private final List<String> offendingElements;

  public ModelProblem(ModelProblemCode modelProblemCode, String message) {
    this(modelProblemCode, message, (Collection)null);
  }

  public ModelProblem(ModelProblemCode modelProblemCode, String message, Collection<String> offendingElements) {
    this.offendingElements = new ArrayList();
    this.modelProblemCode = modelProblemCode;
    this.message = message;
    if (offendingElements != null) {
      this.offendingElements.addAll(offendingElements);
    }

  }

  public ModelProblemCode getModelProblemCode() {
    return this.modelProblemCode;
  }

  public String getMessage() {
    return this.message;
  }

  public List<String> getOffendingElements() {
    return new ArrayList(this.offendingElements);
  }
}
```

`ModelProblemCode` enum is defined in the library as below:

```
public enum ModelProblemCode {
  
  ENUM1("enum message 1"),
  ENUM2("enum message 2"),
  ENUM3("enum message 3"),
  ENUM4("enum message 4"),
  ENUM5("enum message 5"),
  ENUM6("enum message 6");

  private final String message;

  private ModelProblemCode(String message) {
    this.message = message
  }

  public String getMessage() {
    return this.message;
  }
}
```

In the `validate` API, I have to send all the types of validation errors in response.

In order to do this, I need to define an error code for each type of validation defined in the service and I cannot inherit the existing enum `ModelProblemCode`, so I defined one Custom Violation class as below:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class MyCustomViolation {

  private final ModelProblem modelProblem; //this came from Library
  private final MyCustomViolationCode myCustomViolationCode;
  private final String message;

  public MyCustomViolation(ModelProblem modelProblem,
                              MyCustomViolationCode MyCustomViolationCode,
                              String message) {
    this.modelProblem = modelProblem;
    this.myCustomViolationCode = myCustomViolationCode;
    this.message = message;
  }

  public MyCustomViolation(MyCustomViolationCode myCustomViolationCode, String message) {
    this(null, myCustomViolationCode, message);
  }

  public MyCustomViolation(ModelProblem modelProblem) {
    this(modelProblem, null, null);
  }

  public ModelProblem getModelProblem() {
    return this.modelProblem;
  }

  public MyCustomViolationCode getMyCustomViolationCode() {
    return  this.myCustomViolationCode;
  }

  public String getMessage() {
    return this.message;
  }
}
```

`MyCustomViolationCode` enum is defined as below:

```
public enum MyCustomViolationCode {
  CUSTOM_ENUM1("custom message");

  private final String message;
  private MyCustomViolationCode(String message) {
    this.message = message;
  }

  public String getMessage() {
    return this.message;
  }
}
```

In the response to `validate` API where I have integrated with two validators as of now (one of the library and one custom validator that I defined in my service), I am sending the response as `List<MyCustomViolation>` as follows:

```
[
  { //THIS ONE IS COMING FROM VALIDATOR DEFINED IN THE LIBRARY
    "modelProblem": {                    
      "modelProblemCode": "<model problem code>,
      "message": "<model problem error message>",
      "offendingElements": [
        <offendingElement1>
      ]
    }
  },
  {   //THIS ONE IS COMING FROM ONE OF CUSTOM VALIDATOR THAT I DEFINED
    "myCustomViolationCode": "<custom violation code>",
    "message": "<custom violation error message>"
  }
]
```

So, the response does not look good. I mean it does not look uniform across all validators which are called in `validate` API. I am not getting any idea, how would I achieve this.

Could anyone please help here?

Comment: You've only shown a single response, so we don't know if it'll look uniform across other requests...

Comment: Sorry, @Lino I did not understand. Maybe my post is not clear. I actually meant that in validate API I have integration with multiple validators.  In the API response of validate API, I would like the response as a uniform for all types of validators invoked in this validate API flow.